# dumping sql file to database server

Tags: php, mysql

I use command like

```
$command = 'mysql -h 192.168.4.567 -uusername -ppassword databasename < table.sql;
exec($command.' 2>&1',$output,$worked);
```

this works fine. But i noticed that sometimes it tries to dump twice. i am unable to find the issue. Is there any specific reason for this ?

I am doing this in browser and ajax.

Comment: are u using crontab or doing via browser or command line ?

Comment: I am doing this in browser.

Comment: Hmm usually the script should run only once if its requested only once. May be its getting called more than once ?

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty  - I see firebug and only 1 request is fired. And this does not happen always.

Comment: Weird, since there is no specif reason for it to happen with the best of my knowledge I can say.